# Mysql insert conflict

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table  with this columns : [user_id][game_id]
I need to close the game when two player join the game.
I used this code :

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM live_games WHERE game_id = '$gid'"))<2){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO live_games (user_id, game_id) VALUES ('$uid', '$gid')");
echo "You have joined the game";
}else{
echo "Table is full";
}
```

the code will allow only two player to register but some times when there are too many users in the website , this condition will not work and three user will add in the table.
How can i fix?

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. If using the InnoDB storage engine, perform a locking read with [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) within the same transaction as the `INSERT` statement.

   Using PDO:

   ```
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

   $dbh->beginTransaction();
   $qry = $dbh->prepare('
     SELECT COUNT(*) FOR UPDATE FROM live_games WHERE game_id = ?
   ');
   $qry->execute([$gid]);

   if ($qry->fetchColumn() < 2) {
     $qry = $dbh->prepare('
       INSERT INTO live_games (user_id, game_id) VALUES (?, ?)
     ');
     $qry->execute([$uid, $gid]);
     if ($qry->rowCount() && $dbh->commit()) echo 'You have joined the game';
   } else {
     $dbh->rollBack();
     echo 'Table is full';
   }
   ```
2. Change the table structure so that there are two columns, `player1` and `player2` (initially `NULL`) and perform `UPDATE live_games SET player2 = ? WHERE game_id = ? AND player2 IS NULL`, then check the number of affected rows; or
3. Change the table structure so that there is an additional `playerNumber` column and then create a composite `UNQUE` index over `(game_id, playerNumber)`.

Comment: Wooow Thanks. is it possible to do this without PDO ?

Comment: @manfilsoof: You can do it with mysqli.   I wouldn't try with the ancient and soon-to-be-deprecated ext/mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You're running two queries to see if someone can enter a game.

It's entirely possible that three players are clicking to join at the same time, and the SELECT query is returning that the game (currently) has 0 players; so they're all allowed in - the UPDATEs then kicks, and stops other players from joining in.

If you want to fix it, you'll need to find another way of doing it - you can add a file lock, so that only one SELECT query is run at once, or I believe that wrapping it in a transaction will also work - that essentially runs both queries as a single entity.

Comment: Being within the same transaction alone will not make any difference, as `SELECT` does not leave records locked by default.

Comment: @eggyal - is there a way to do this with transactions? I'm not familiar enough with them to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your queries with [**LOCK TABLES**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) statement, like this:

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES live_games WRITE");

if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM live_games WHERE game_id = '$gid'"))<2){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO live_games (user_id, game_id) VALUES ('$uid', '$gid')");
echo "You have joined the game";
}else{
echo "Table is full";
}

mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

that will enforce serial access to your table, so avoiding concurrency problems by different users executing the same code at the same time.

Comment: Will cause an awful lot of needless blocking.

Comment: This is a good solution , but i have several open games in this table and locking the table will affect the other players joining the other games (diffrent game_id's).

Comment: Can i lock the rows with special game_id ?

Comment: Not if you are using MyISAM tables (which you probably do) if you want locking at the row level you need to use InnoDB.

Comment: I use Inno , how to locking at the row level?